# Python random dice

Tags: python, random

I'm a student at the university and they're teaching us Python. Today we had to do in the university a control with dictionaries that was the following:
**Generate a dictionary with the results of the sum of two dice thrown at random, in a thousand experiments.**

My doubt is that I did it in the following way but the teacher told me that it was wrong, I would like you to give me your opinion about it.

```
from random import randrange

dosdados = {}
for x in range (1,1001):
    dado1 = randrange(1,7)
    dado2 = randrange(1,7)  
    dosdados[x] = dado1 + dado2

print (dosdados)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Spanish Stack Overflow / Stack Overflow en español : https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on es.stackoverflow

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau I already write it in english.

Comment: @Goyo I change it to english

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i change it :)

Comment: If your teacher told you it was wrong, why didn't you ask them?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nah, I still don't think it's a good, clear question. How does it deviate from the expected behavior?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Sorry, did not read the english version... only went on a leap of faith :-(

Comment: @JohnDvorak what ?? thats the kind of question that my teacher give me.

Comment: @RominaAlarcon Keep it respectful.

Comment: @jhpratt Im asking for a simple question that my teacher give us. I will want help.

Comment: @jhpratt Cause some teacher just said that is wrong and they dont explain. I thought that here i can ask.

Comment: @Romina I do not think this is answerable without a clear statement about what exactly is wrong. Your teacher telling you just "this is wrong" is not helpful at all and we can't read their mind better than you --at least you know them. If your teacher don't want to be more helpful you petty sure are have a problem but certainly not a problem related to programming.

Comment: @Goyo Thanks but the type of way I store the values in the dictionary is bad? thats a big question i have. I really dont get it why he said is wrong, I thought it was a bad way of making a dictionary with random numbers.

Comment: @RominaAlarcon The task's description is unclear. What should be the keys of the dictionary? What should be the values? We can only guess and we can fail as much as you did. Only the teacher can answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were supposed to count the number of times a certain sum appeared.

```
from random import randrange

dosdados = {}
for x in range (1,1001):
    dado1 = randrange(1,7)
    dado2 = randrange(1,7)  

    if dado1 + dado2 in dosdados:
      dosdados[dado1 + dado2] += 1
    else:
      dosdados[dado1 + dado2] = 1

print (dosdados)
```

Comment: Chronus thanks for your answer, but I will like to know why the way I did it is wrong. My teacher told us to make this: Generate a dictionary with the results of the sum of two dice thrown at random, in a thousand experiments.

Comment: Obviously i can't have 100% sure of what your teacher asked. But the way i interpret the enunciate, your professor wants you to count how many times a determined sum occurred. However, you were just recording that at some point X a sum Y appeared. My modification to your code makes the program store a given sum and, if it occurs again, increments the number of times that appeared.

Comment: ohh! ok thanks so much Chronus, Im trying to understand what you did :).

Comment: I can explain it to you. So imagine at a certain iteration you have a sum of 10. You need to check if your dictionary already has a key equal to 10. If it has, then you increment the value related to it, otherwise you add to the dictionary the key-value <10, 1>.

Comment: I think you mean "The teacher intended to have you count the number of times a certain sum appeared." Also, you can replace four lines of your code with just `dosdados[dado1 + dado2] = dosdados.get(dado1 + dado2,0)+1`. Or initialize `dosdados` as `{total:0 for total in range(2,13)}` and then do `dosdados[dado1 + dado2] += 1`. This will result in any total that isn't rolled have a value of 0, rather than be missing from the dictionary entirely.

Comment: BTW this is a one-liner `Counter(randrange(1,7)+randrange(1,7) for i in range(1000))`